# Multiple Password attempts pg_dump python

Tags: python, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

I am trying to allow the user of my script to prompt users to enter the correct password if they have entered an invalid one. I am not sure whether this a psql configuration or if its done by using error handling with python. Which one do I use and how? My current code is as follows:

```
 backup_ps = subprocess.Popen(
    ['pg_dump','-h', ORIGIN_DB, '-U', ORIGIN_DB_USER, ORIGIN_DB_NAME, '-f', destination, '-c',
     '-t', 'table1',
     '-Fp', '--inserts'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)

output = backup_ps.communicate()[0]

# if password incorrect, prompt for correct password.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running `postgresql96` on FreeBSD. When I enter a bad password the return code for `pg_dump` is 1, rather than 0.

A naive solution would be to put your code in a while loop like this:

```
while True:
    backup_ps = subprocess.Popen(
        ['pg_dump','-h', ORIGIN_DB, '-U', ORIGIN_DB_USER, ORIGIN_DB_NAME, '-f', destination, '-c',
            '-t', 'table1',
            '-Fp', '--inserts'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    output = backup_ps.communicate()[0]
    if backup_ps.returncode == 0:
        break
```

The problem is that `pg_dump` will likely return 1 on any error, including when system calls to allocate memory or disk space fail. So it doesn't actually mean that the password input failed, and you might want a hook to exit without a successful return after `n` tries or using something else.

Another solution might be to check if the dump output file exists and was recently modified. You might also want to inspect stderr for the error message that talks about a bad password.

I think those solutions are hacky.

The best solution (AFAICT) is to not use a separate process to do the dump (because then communicating with that process can be a pain in the ass), but use a Python library, like [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) to access the database.

Comment: Thank you so much this did the trick, I had a feeling it might have to do with the return code

Comment: Cool, and yeah sorry about the original sloppiness. I write in C and Ruby as well, so I sometimes write `true` rather than `True` or put semicolons on the end of statements like a maniac.

Comment: hahah no problem!, I am a bit of a python noob. Java dev myself